# How does a layman differentiate between positive lightning and negative lightning?

Tags: meteorology

Yes, there are different types of [Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Positive_and_negative_lightning). How can general public/audience detect if a cloud to ground lightning strike was of positive or negative type?